# Closing event fired twice when set the exitButton.IsCancel = True

Tags: wpf, events, button

I realized when I set the exit button with attribute IsCancel = True, the Closing event of window will fire twice.

```
    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this button was set attribute IsCancel = True.
        Close();          
    }

    private void BaseWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {          
        MessageBox.Show("test"); // this message box will show twice
                                 // when you click on the exit button
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Is this a bug of WPF ? Is there a workaround ?

**Ps : Sorry I forgot to say this bug only occurs when you call your window from a parent window.**

Comment: What happens if you remove `e.Cancel = true` so the window actually closes?

Comment: yes, the window will close if I remove **e.Cancel = true**.

Comment: But I want the window cancels closing so I need to set **e.Cancel = true**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess I don't see where this is unexpected behaviour.

If you designate this as the `Cancel` button and call `.ShowDialog()`, then clicking the button will close the window.

You've added your own call to `Close()` and canceled the close, so both calls are made and the event is raised both times.

#### update

In answer to your comment about why it might behave the way it does, the `IsCancel` and `IsDefault` properties provide an easy mechanism to define dialogs using XAML only. They save you the trouble of having to go into the codebehind to define boilerplate click handlers.

Comment: I think it should be one call to **exitButton_Click** if it behaves right. IsCancel = True just for activating **exitButton_Click** when user presses ESC. Moreover, this only occurs when you call this window (which contains this exit button) from another window. So I think this is a bug.

Comment: you're right. When I use .ShowDialog() there will be more one extra close() to be called if I set IsCancel = True. I don't understand why MS design thing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not assigning the event more than once. For example in xaml Window class definition

```
<Window x:Class="... Closing="Dialog_Closing">
```

and in the C# code behind.

```
Closing += Dialog_Closing;
```